# Python: Iris Data Set, include the species

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code and it returns me the min and max values of the chosen column, however, I would also like to include the species that this value relates to. I have also included the column names in the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("iris head.csv")

print(min(df['Sepal Length']))
print(max(df['Sepal Length']))
```

Comment: Please mention proper output for the above code. questions seems confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC is as follows:

```
df.groupby(['class'])['Sepal Length'].agg(['max','min'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!